# JavaScript: duplicate object with only specified fields

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to duplicate an object with only specified fields? For example:

```js
const a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'baz',
  baz: 'foo',
}

// Duplicate of a with only foo and baz properties
const b = { foo: 'bar', baz: 'foo' }
```

I know I could do

```js
b = {
  foo: a.foo,
  baz: a.baz,
}
```

but this seems like a long walk for a short drink of water. What's the quickest way to clone an object as a partial with specified fields?

**EDIT: April 8th**

I would also like to be able to do this inline, as follows:

```js
const a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'baz',
  baz: 'foo',
}

const obj = {
  b: { foo: 'bar', baz: 'foo' }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to destructure the property you want to exclude out, and use rest syntax:

```js
const a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'baz',
  baz: 'foo',
};
const { bar, ...b } = a;
console.log(b);
```

If you want to put it into an object, destructure on the line above where you declare the object:

```js
const a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'baz',
  baz: 'foo',
};
const { bar, ...b } = a;
const obj = { b };
console.log(obj);
```

If you have a large number of properties you want to exclude, use `Object.entries` to get an array of entries, filter them, then use `Object.fromEntries` to turn it back into an object:

```js
const a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'baz',
  baz: 'foo',
};
const propsToRemove = ['foo', 'bar'];
const obj = {
  b: Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(a).filter(([key]) => !propsToRemove.includes(key))
  )
};
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Ah, good idea. Unfortunately I don't think that'll work in my case, as I actually have to do this inline without a definition. I'll edit my post to clarify.

Comment: Also, this doesn't quite work out because, for larger objects, it would be necessary to list every undesired key when destructuring.

Comment: For `larger` objects, how do you know the unnecessary fields?

Answer (score 0):

Make the destructuring a function and call it with the original object `a`.

```js
const a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'baz',
  baz: 'foo',
}

const b = (({ foo, baz }) => ({ foo, baz }))(a);

console.log(b);
```

You can also pass it into an object.

```js
const a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'baz',
  baz: 'foo',
}

const obj = {
    b: (({ foo, baz }) => ({ foo, baz }))(a),
};

console.log(obj);
```

More about destructuring: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)